# ORACLE REF Cursor with Dynamic table name inside a Dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, cursors, sys-refcursor

We have a scenario where in a table name should be passed in to a REF Cursor dynamically. The table name is build inside another dynamic sql and oracle doesn't build the SQL properly. Here is the PLSQL block

```
DECLARE
  c_TableCreated NUMBER := 0;
  strDynamicSQL VARCHAR2(4000);
  strDynamicSQL1 VARCHAR2(4000);   
BEGIN  
dbms_output.ENABLE;
strDynamicSQL := 'CREATE DIRECTORY testdir as ''C:\Temp\UID''';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strDynamicSQL;
strDynamicSQL := 'CREATE TABLE temp11 (
                      UID       VARCHAR2(128),
                      Source    VARCHAR2(50),
                      TABLENAME    VARCHAR(50))
                      Organization external
                      (type oracle_loader
                      default directory testdir
                      access parameters (records delimited by newline
                      fields terminated by ''##'')
                      location (''SourceUIDs.txt''))
                      reject limit 1000';   
  
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strDynamicSQL;
    c_TableCreated := 1;
    strDynamicSQL := '
    DECLARE
    c_UID   nvarchar2(128);
    c_ID   nvarchar2(128);
    c_DEFUID varchar2(128);
    c_class varchar2(40);
    c_SOURCE  varchar2(50);
    c_TableName VARCHAR2(50);
    v_emp_refcur    SYS_REFCURSOR;
    CURSOR lcsrTablePrefixes IS SELECT DISTINCT TABLENAME FROM temp11;
    
    PROCEDURE GetCURSOR(pstrTableName IN VARCHAR2, p_emp_refcur IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
    BEGIN 
       OPEN p_emp_refcur FOR SELECT S.ID,S.UID,S.DEFUID,S.CLASS, U.Source  FROM pstrTableName S INNER JOIN temp11 U ON U.OBJUID = S.OBJUID
        WHERE UPPER(U.TABLENAME) = UPPER(pstrTableName );
    END;
    
    BEGIN
    FOR J IN lcsrTablePrefixes LOOP
      c_TableName := J.TABLENAME;
      GetCURSOR(c_TableName, v_emp_refcur);
      LOOP
        FETCH v_emp_refcur INTO c_ID,c_UID,c_DEFUID,c_class,c_SOURCE;
        dbms_output.put_line(c_ID);
        EXIT WHEN v_emp_refcur%NOTFOUND;        
    END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    END;';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strDynamicSQL;
  strDynamicSQL := 'DROP DIRECTORY testdir';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strDynamicSQL;
  strDynamicSQL := 'Drop Table temp11';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strDynamicSQL;
  strDynamicSQL := NULL;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  IF c_TableCreated = 1 THEN   
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP DIRECTORY testdir';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table temp11';
  END IF; 
    RAISE;
END;
```

Upon running the block we receive an error "table or view does not exist" and it is from the GetCursor procedure that builds the cursor dynamically using the passed in table name parameter. Since this is already inside a dynamic block ORACLE couldn't identify the table name.

Is there a way to pass in a variable dynamically inside another dynamic SQL statement?

The requirement is this

1. Read the text file from a specified location into a temp table. This needs to be inside a dynamic sql since oracle doesn't allow creation of tables inside PLSQL. Text file contains the list of IDs and the table name where it can be found.
2. Get the list of unique table names from the temp table and join it against each matching table in Database and the get the list of IDs for further processing.

Any help or suggestions on how to overcome this? Thanks in advance

Comment: "FROM pstrTableName" - you can't do that.  It thinks pstrTableName is the actual table name.  This seems like an overly-complicated task.

Comment: Why are you dynamically building an external table? Dynamic creation of tables in transactional flow is always a red flag. Table's are supposed to be **permanent features** of our schema. Maybe you just need something to change the name / location of the file which feeds the external table?

Comment: Just noticed you're always creating and dropping the directory object as well. Oh boy!

Comment: What's your exact oracle version? External tables have more features in newer versions

Comment: we are on oracle 19 and there is a restriction on loading external file using temporary tables or is there a way to achieve this using temporary tables?